# How do you query namespaces with PHP/XPath/DOM

Tags: php, xml, dom, xpath, namespaces

I am trying to query an XML document that uses namespaces.  I have had success with xpath without namespaces, but no results with namespaces.  This is a basic example of what I was trying.  I have condensed it slightly, so there may be small issues in my sample that may detract from my actual problem.

Sample XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<sf:page>
     <sf:section>
          <sf:layout>
              <sf:p>My Content</sf:p>
          </sf:layout>
     </sf:section>
</sf:page>
```

Sample PHP Code:

```
<?php
$path = "index.xml";

$content = file_get_contents($path);

$dom = new DOMDocument($content);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('sf', "http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sf");

$p = $xpath->query("//sf:p", $dom);
```

My result is that "p" is a "DOMNodeList Object ( )" and it's length is 0.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You have no namespace declaration in your XML? Missing an xmlns:sf="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sf"?

Comment: Vincent, that is only a result of trying to condense my code into a sample.  The following xml was part of the original XML:
<sl:document xmlns:sfa="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sfa" xmlns:sf="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sf" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:sl="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sl" sl:version="92008102400" sl:generator="slingshot" sl:app_build_date="Sep 23 2009, 18:04:26">

Maybe I am not understanding something as well.

Answer (score 2):

DOMDocument constructor does not take the contents, but version and encoding.
Instead of:

```
$path = "index.xml";
$content = file_get_contents($path);
$dom = new DOMDocument($content);
```

Try this:

```
$path = "index.xml";
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load($path);
```

Answer (score 0):

You must define namespace in your xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns:sf="http://developer.apple.com/namespaces/sf">
    <sf:page>
         <sf:section>
              <sf:layout>
                  <sf:p>My Content</sf:p>
              </sf:layout>
         </sf:section>
    </sf:page>
</root>
```